# What does poll(NULL, 0, timeout) mean?

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm looking at `strace` output that includes a call to the syscall `poll()`:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html

(This is on a Debian system, I forget kernel version.)

I keep seeing calls that look like `poll(NULL, 0, intrger_here)`. What happens when you call `poll()` with `pollfd` set to `NULL` like this?  Why would a program be doing this?

(I suppose I should refer to kernel source.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basically a longhand way of writing a `sleep()` of `timeout` duration.

Comment: Actually it's more a replacement for `nanosleep()`, but with millisecond resolution.